# Regex: Match all characters between { and } if a specific string is between them

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string like this:

```
{name|val1|test}{name|val1|test}
```

And what I need is a RegEx which selects

```
{name|val1|test}
```

for example. Is that possible? I'm playing with [Online RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) for a while now but it seems that i'm to dumb to understand the syntax ;-) Currently I'm able to seperate the {...} groups:

```
\{.+?\}
```

The "syntax" of this strings is fix. It's not possible that there are brackets inside brackets.

The language is C#

**Edited for clearance:**

I want to select only one of the strings, depending on the value in the middle. For example, if im looking for "ID1" i only want to select the brackets and whats between them when they are containing "ID1".

[image]

Comment: `"The thing is, {strings {can have} nested brackets} or even {brackets {that don't match} others!"`

Comment: The "syntax" that there are no brackets inside brackets is fix.

Comment: Put for his pupose. The regex is correct :-)

Comment: I don't really get what you're asking. What is that expression not doing that you want it to do? (Or what is it doing that you want it to not do?)

Comment: as far as I can tell your regex does what it's supposed to do.  http://rubular.com/r/GJoKjmqT4V

Comment: What programming language or text editor (to include IDEs also) is this ultimately going to be used in?

Comment: saw your edit, and most regex engines have the capability to just account for the first match, but that's entirely dependent on the context your regex will be in

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @JohnSaunders Sorry, I will keep an eye on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put the id inside the regex so that you match it:

```
/\{[^}]*ID1[^}]*\}/
```